# Use facet_zoom in a stat_density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I'd like to use facet_zoom but for some reason the zoomed area results empty.

The two data sets I use are just numeric vectors of 1.000.000 numbers generated from a modified polynomial distribution. In the zoomed area there is a small spike that I'd like to show.

```
prova <-readRDS("probcond1.rds")
prova1 <-readRDS("probpoly.rds")
dfGamma <-data.frame(prova)

ggplot(dfGamma, aes(x=prova)) + stat_density(aes(y=..count..), color="black", fill="blue", alpha=0.3)

g <- ggplot(dfGamma, aes(x=prova)) +
  stat_density(aes(y=..count..), color="black", fill="blue", alpha=0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10,30,100,300,1000,4000,5000), trans="log1p", expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw()

g+expand_limits(x = c(1, 6000)) +facet_zoom(xlim = c(4000,5000))
```

I'm really new to R. sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 2):

Your `axis` is on a `log1p` scale, so your `xlim` should be wrapped inside `log1p` to do a zoom. You can do as follows:

```r
g+expand_limits(x = c(1, 6000)) +facet_zoom(xlim = c(log1p(4000),log1p(5000)))
```

Here is a sample using the `mtcars` dataset.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp)) +
  stat_density(aes(y=..count..), color="black", fill="blue", alpha=0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10,30,100,300), trans="log1p", expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

If you use  `facet_zoom(xlim = c(100,300))` as follows will produce empty zoom output (flat values of 100 and 300 don't exist on the g's x-axis):

```r
g+expand_limits(x = c(1, 300)) +facet_zoom(xlim = c(100,300))
```

## Output-1 (flat value zoom)

[image: zoom_empty]

If you transform the `xlim` using `log1p`, you can zoom on the corresponding values of the `x-axis` of plot `g`. You can do that as follows:

```r
g+expand_limits(x = c(1, 300)) +facet_zoom(xlim = c(log1p(100),log1p(300)))
```

## Output-2 (log1p zoom)

[image: zoom_proper]

If you want to `zoom` in the axis independently, you can do as follows:

```r
g+expand_limits(x = c(1, 300)) +facet_zoom(xlim = c(log1p(100),log1p(300)), ylim = c(5,10), split = TRUE)
```

## Output

[image: zoom_xy_indpt]

As you can see I did zoom the `ylim` between `5` and `10` and the `split = TRUE` makes the zoom independent and you can have multiple views of the zoom axis or if you just want one view, you can leave the `split` to its default value `FALSE`. The manual has a lot more information which you might want to consult, just in case it is available at [Package ‘ggforce’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggforce/ggforce.pdf)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have just one more question: if I want to limit also the y axis, since the peak is really small compared to the rest, how can I do it? If I put a ylim It doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: See the update. You can do `ylim` and zoom in to the range of axis values you want.

Comment: Thank you again, it works now. The only thing is that the zoom appears on the left which is weird because the zoomed area is on the right of the graph. Moreover I’d like to change the aspect ratio, in particular the height of the zoomed graph, the only option I found is zoom.size but it’s not exactly what I’m looking for.

Comment: https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/issues/126 something like this.